# Visual Studio 2012 - cannot find vsvars32.bat to use gacutil to install extra tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I am running Visual Studio 2012 (version 11.0.50727.1)

I have been trying to install https://jsonsource.codeplex.com/, a tool to allow JSON data to be imported using SSIS. To install this, once I have copied the dll's into the correct folder, I need to register them using gacutilexe. this is where my problem starts. I am supposed to run Gacutil.exe from the Visual Studio command line. This is supposed to be present in the Start Menu as VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt (it isn't), I am also supposed to be able to access it using vsvars32.bat (using the add external tools menu in Visual Studio, and supplying the location of vsvars32.bat as an argument). However, I cannot find vsvars32.bat anywhere within my C drive.

I have found several versions of GacUtil.exe in various subfolders of C:\program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows, although the installation guide lead me to believe it should be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents, i.e. where I copied the dll's for the tool I am installing. I'm not sure which of these (if any) I should be using once I get to the visual studio command prompt. Could do with advice here as well.

vsvars32 is meant to be somewhere within C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools, but it is definitely not present any where within the Visual Studio folder.. There are also folders for Visual Studio 9 and 10, but these do not contain vsvar32 anywhere within them either.

if anyone could help I would be very much indebted - My options as to how to deal with the JSON source files otherwise are extremely limited. (using Management Studio 2012 rather than 2016, so can't use OPENJSON. If anyone can suggest any alternatives, let me know. This includes just any option to get the entire JSON file file into a cell - I could probably build some kind of extensive string manipulation to script to split it all out once I've got them in there, although this seems like entirely the wrong way to go about things...)

Answer (score 0):

The first time you install the 3rd party package in Nuget Package manager, it will automatically download the .dll to your user temp folder, once you close it, it will gone, but it will register for you. If you need to find where the exactly location is, simply double click that new added .dll in solution window, if you try to reinstall, but it does not allow you to do that, delete the **package.config** file, and try to reinstall that package. Once that is added again, do not forget to double click that .dll, to see where is reside, move to your own folder, register using `gacutil -i` command, and should be good.